# Angular 5- pass data between sibling components to use at the same time

Tags: angular, http

I have an Angular app where I have two sibling components being rendered at the same time, and they need the same data. (One is a nav bar listing all the sites, and the other is in my router outlet that lists all the sites/graphs the data etc.)

In order to make fewer http requests want to make a call to the service one time, store the data in a global variable, then access that data from the sibling component.

But, since they're both loading at the same time, the data called from one component doesn't have time to make it into the service before the other component tries to receive it from the service.

**Component A** (storing the data in a global variable 'all_sites' in the service)

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getSites()
    .subscribe(data => {
    this.sites = data
    this.myService.all_sites = data
  })
}
```

**Component B** Comes up undefined.

```
 ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.myService.all_sites)
 }
```

So is there a way for me to send data to a sibling component and get them both to use the data at the same time?
Like I'm doing this in the parent:

```
<app-componentA></app-componentA>
<app-componentB></app-componentB>
```

Other complications make it difficult to just call from the parent (Authtoken2 stuff). My ultimate goal is to lighten the load on the server

Thanks!! Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Cache the `Observable` and return that same instance in the service.

Comment: I'd recommend reading: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using component A and component B in one component. So can you make that http call in that parent and use ngIf something like:

```
<div *ngIf="this.sites.length">
<app-componentA></app-componentA>
<app-componentB></app-componentB>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing IN component A ngOnInit(), you can actullay do it in the parent component ngOnInit() and pass this.sites as inputs to both of the siblings.

in that manner, you can achieve what you want. less requests and children will load once the parent is loaded and called the service

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to enforce this scenario**:

Create a `Subject` which emits a value when the http response arrives. After that it is pretty simple, you can just subscribe to this `Observable` to get the data in your other component.

**Send http request in parent component**:

An other simple solution is to send the request the parent component and pass the value to the child components with `Input`.

**Consider using redux**:

`Redux` is a really powerful tool. You can store the response in state and `Observers` in child components will be notified with selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try 
`Object.assign(this.myService.all_sites, data)`
instead of
`this.myService.all_sites = data`

Comment: Matt, Lauren want to get the SAME object, Using Object.assign create two independent objects

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that both components call `ngOnInit` before returned observable from the service in the call made from `componentA` has been resolved. So in the call made by `componentB` the field `all_sites` is still `undefined`.

The easiest way to do this is to cache the observable and have all components still access the method. Only the service should know/care about caching.

```
export class MyService {
    private getSitesObservable: Observable<Sites[]>;
    getSites(): Observable<Sites[]> {
        if(!this.getSitesObservable)
            this.getSitesObservable = this.http.....;
        return this.getSitesObservable;
    }
}
```

And then in both components (or any component that calls this service's method):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getSites().subscribe(data => {
        this.sites = data;
  });
}
```

Comment: Correct me please if I am wrong, but this way, @LaurenAh still has to send two requests.

Comment: @BalázsTakács - No, the observable is only resolved once. Only one call will be made to the server.

Comment: I mean she still has to subscribe to this observable in two different places, which means two different requests will be sent.

Comment: @BalázsTakács - No. Although you subscribe two times there is only one http call. The observable will respond to any request made after it has been resolved with the same value. The benefit here is that the components dont have to care if there is a cached result or not (or even if there is caching). Order of subscription also does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the service call logic into the parent component that houses both the components, and passing the data in as inputs:

so the structure would be as follows

```
<app-component-parent>
    <app-component-a></app-component-a>
    <app-component-b></app-component-b>
<app-component-parent>
```

In app-component-parent.component.ts, call the service on ngOnInit:

```
sites: SITES_TYPE;

ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getSites()
    .subscribe(data => {
    this.sites = data
  })
}
```

Then in the siblings, pass 'sites' in as an input:

```
<app-component-a [sites]="sites"></app-component-a>
<app-component-b [sites]="sites"></app-component-b>
```

And in each of the components, do the following:

```
@Input()
sites: SITES_TYPE;
```